# SQL Server 2014 subquery insert values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, subquery, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have created a table `DepDS` with columns `(Regno, Stname, Depatrment, Year, Batch, Vote)`

I have registered values to all rows except `Vote` through **VB.NET**, now I want to enter value into vote by the condition: `Where Regno = '"& ds1 &"'`

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO DepDS(Regno, StName, Department, StYear, Batch, Photo) 
                    VALUES(@regno, @name, @department, @year, @batch, @photo)")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", txtregno.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department",cmbdept.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", cmbyear.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", cmbbatch.Text)
```

I just want to know how to use where condition in this query

I tried many queries and all of then failed, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Which sql engine (and version) are you using?

Comment: include your tried code

Comment: I tried many but nothing works,.its quite a lot..

Comment: @ianaya89 Ms sql server14

Comment: One thing, There is no way to use Where Clause in Insert statement,   Let us know, what functionality you tried to implement, so we can suggest you

Comment: You **cannot** have a condition on an `INSERT` statement - the `INSERT` will just insert those values that you give it. But I assume you want to actually use an `UPDATE` statement instead - **updating** an existing row, and *there* you can (and should!) specify a condition in the `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding it very difficult to understand your question, and it can be interpreted in may ways, but it sounds like you want to UPDATE the value of Vote

```
Where Regno = '"& ds1 &"'
```

If you wanted to UPDATE the value of Vote, you need an UPDATE statement, not an INSERT

```
UPDATE DepDS SET Vote = @Vote WHERE Regno = @RegNo
```

I apologise if this is not what you asked.